# Why does variable not change?

Tags: c++, mingw

I have just finished learning how to use the random function, so i decided to make a small casino Game. However, my code does not update the `double Money;` variable. That is I cannot set, add, or subtract a value to or from this variable. I am having trouble determining why this is happening.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
  double Money;//Variable Money;

  srand ( time(0) );
  int randomNumber;
  randomNumber = (1+(rand() % 10));
  cout << "\nEnter your Starting Money: ";
  int Guess;
  cin >> Money;
  cout << "Your Starting money is: " << Money;
  cout << "\nGuess the number between 1 and 10: ";
  start:
  cin >> Guess;
  if(Guess == randomNumber)
  {
    Money + 10;
    cout << "You were correct! The number was " << randomNumber << "!";
  }
  else
  {
    Money - 10;//Nothing Happens
    cout << "You were wrong! Your money is now: " << Money << "\nRetry Please: ";
    goto start;
  }
  char f;
  cin >> f;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not setting the variable, try `Money = Money + 10`

Answer (score 6):

```
Money + 10;
```

is a statement that has no side effects. You want

```
Money += 10;
```

which is equivalent to

```
Money = Money + 10;
```

Think about it, if you wrote

```
4 + 5;
```

would you expect `4` to become `9`? ...

Answer (score 1):

`money - 10;` is a valid C and C++ expression that (conceptually) calculates that value then throws away the result, much the same as `42;`.

Use `money = money - 10;` or `money -= 10;` instead. Ditto for the adding as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the new vale to `Money`

`Money = Money + 10` or , as mentioned, `Money += 10`

Answer (score 0):

Money + 10 doesnt change the value if you want to change the value use Money = Money + 10
you may also use Money += 10
and btw instead of char f; cin >> f; .. cout << endl; system("pause"); looks better